# Error al eliminar una coleccion o DB en MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, iis, windows-server-2012

Buen dia, espero me puedan ayudar, agradezco de antemano su apoyo.
Tengo varias db en mongodb, lo que experimento es que al eliminar una db o cuando abro alguna coleccion me marca el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

esta situacion la tengo con db y colecciones en epecifico, no son todas. Mi duda sería a que se debe? y como forzo la eliminacion de estas db o colecciones. 
PD. ya he leido y buscado en internet incluso en foros de mongo y no he encontrado antecedente alguno.

Comment: Has intentado reparar las bases de datos por si fuera un problema de corrupción?

Comment: Hola @Pikoh, si lo he hecho, estoy usando Robo3T y de ahi le doy en reparar db y me sale exactamente el mismo mensaje

Comment: Tal vez deberías probar a desinstalar/instalar/actualizar mongo, por si fuera algún problema de instalacion o de version. Mas allá de ahi no puedo ayudarte ya que no tengo mucha experiencia con MongoDB, tal vez algun usuario con mas conocimiento pueda darte alguna pista mejor :)

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia @Pikoh , si lo he estado evaluando, como mi ultima opción debido a las implicaciones que tendría. Ojalá alguien mas vea el post y me apoye con sus comentarios también. Saludos!